# How to construct bitcoin Merkle tree?

Tags: c++, tree, bitcoin

I am learning the Bitcoin mining protocol, however, I confuse about creating a Merkle tree. Let say 1 got 1 x coinbase transaction and 3 transaction id. Is the process as illustrate in the picture below/attach correctly?

From my understanding, all coinbase and transaction id must be changed first to little-endian before double sha256 hash is calculated.

Hash from coinbase will become the first leaf, tx1 become the second leaf and tx3 become the last leaf.

Then combine 2 hash before double hash again and so the process goes up the pyramid structure until the root is found before it is changed back to big-endian.

Hope someone can guide me on this. Thanks in advance

[image: Picture of Structure based on my understanding]

Answer (score -1):

for coinbase tx all things take place here
https://github.com/alexeyneu/BlockZero/blob/73744a4ae93e367d617692b2f2d81fbf88143715/BlockZero.cpp#L80-L82

```cpp
SHA256(serializedData, sizeof transaction + 1 + scriptSig_length, hash1);  /* + 1 coz of serializedData[sizeone]*/
blockheader block_header = {1/*version*/,{}/*hprev*/,{}/*merk*/,unixtime == 0 ? time(NULL) : unixtime ,nBits ,startNonce };
SHA256(hash1, 32, block_header.merk);// hash it with SHA256 and then hash that result to get merkle hash
```

what i can say about picture:
little indian stuff depends on that how someone you'd received all this from wanna see it. big endian is mostly for display purpose. if you grab it on your own you'll have it on le already. and i do not understand what means "tx in big endian".and what you mean by "convert to le". there's a script there and if you decide to "convert" it... idk what to say